# Why is ipRouteMetric1 affected by ipRouteProto in snmp ipRouteTable?

Tags: router, snmp, iproute, routetable

I am doing a simulation of the network topology.

I found that when using the **rip** protocol, the **ipRouteMetric1** value is 1. I use this value to determine the device near the current router. When using the **ospf** protocol, the value of the nearby router **ipRouteMetric1** is 2.

I can't understand why the data is so different based on the **ipRouteTable** generated by different protocols. I would like to know if there will be new differences for other protocols, such as **bgp**.

Comment: Make the network bigger, and add loops. You will see that the metric values basically tell the distance of the quickest path to that route.

Comment: I know that in fact my question is not because the metric has a value of 2. I just think that the metric between two adjacent routers should be 1, and the ospf protocol shows this value as 2, which I doubt. In addition, when I tested the **ip route-static** command, I found that the metric is even 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RFC1213-MIB https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1213 is quite SPECIFIC in its
vagueness:

"The semantics of this metric are determined by the routing-protocol specified
in the route's ipRouteProto value."

So, you have to look at the protocol specs for the particular routing protocol
to understand the metric calculation. A Google for OSPF metric explains the metric
calculated based on "cost".